# Bib renames its items itself and one does not even show up

Tags: bibtex

Want to include my literature in a beamer frame
but it causes weird issues.

It lists the second and third item as (Dij59a and Dij59b)

```
@article{Bac54, 
    author={Backus, John W.},
    title={The IBM 701 Speedcoding System},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the 17th Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms},
    number= {1},
    year={1954},
    volume ={1},
    pages={4--6}
}
@phdthesis{Dij59,
    author= {Dijkstra, Edsger W.},
    title = {Communication with an Automatic Computer},
    school = {University of Amsterdam},
    type = {Diss.},
    year = {1959}
}
@unpublished{Dij62,
    author= {Dijkstra, Edsger W.},
    title = {Substitution processes},
    month = {Januar},
    year = {1959},
    note = {privat verbreitet}
}
@article{Dij68,
    author= {Dijkstra, Edsger W.},
    title = {Cooperating sequential processes},
    booktitle={Genuys, F. (Hrsg.): Programming Languages: NATO Advanced Study Institute},
    school = {University of Amsterdam},
    type = {Academic Press},
    year = {1968},
    pages={43--112}
}
@book{KR78,
    author= {Kernighan, Brian W. ; Ritchie, Dennis.},
    title = {Communication with an Automatic Computer},
    school = {University of Amsterdam},
    type = {Diss.},
    publisher= {Prentice-Hall},
    year = {1978}

}
@inproceedings{Pnu77,
    author= {Pnueli, Amir},
    title = {The Temporal Logic of Programs},
    booktitle= {18th Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science},
    school = {University of Amsterdam},
    organization = {IEEE Computer Society},
    year = {1977},
    pages = {46--57}
}
```

Latex lines:

```
Edsger Dijkstra war ein niederländischer Informatiker, der in seiner
Dissertation \cite{Dij59} eine Programmiersprache für die Electrologica X1
entwickelte. Die X1 war ein Digital-Computer, der in den 1950er Jahren
in den Niederlanden produziert wurde. Neben seiner Dissertation sei hier
noch auf ein nicht veröffentlichtes Paper \cite{Dij62} und ein Beitrag in einem
Sammelband \cite{Dij68} verwiesen.

Amir Pnueli war ein israelischer Informatiker, der wegweisende
Verdienste um die Einführung der temporalen Logik \cite{Pnu77} in die Informatik
geleistet hat.

Der IBM 701 war der erste für wissenschaftliche Zwecke bestimmte Rechner
von IBM. Sein Speedcoding System wird von John Backus im Journal-Artikel \cite{Bac54}
beschrieben. The C Programming Language \cite{Kr78} ist das erste Buch über die
Programmiersprache C.
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete, self contained [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: This is my whole bibtex document

Comment: Regarding "It lists the second and third item as (Dij59a and Dij59b)": Both are written by the same author in the same year. Therefore "a"  and "b"  are added to distinguish them.

Comment: well thanks how can i stop it from doing that if i have a case in which it is in the same year by the same author? In my case my year is wrong.

Comment: @RackCloud - fix the year if it's wrong

Comment: The `year` in both `Dij59` and `Dij62` is given as `1959`, but it stands to reason that the `year` in `Dij62` should actually be `1962`. Note that regardless of the desired output of several names, names must be separated with `and` in the `.bib` file. It should be `author = {Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis},` in `KR78`. `@article` entries don't usually have a `booktitle`, so `Dij68` is probably an `@incollection`. The editor of an `@incollection` belongs into the `editor` field and not into the `booktitle`.

Comment: Re the minimal example: We not only need to see your `.bib` file (or rather the relevant entries of the `.bib` file, we don't need to see all of it),  we also need to see a minimal, yet complete `.tex` document using the `.bib` entries. In case of questions about bibliographies, the MWE needs to show which citation/bibliography packages you load (`cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...) and which style you use (the argument to `\bibliographystyle`). If this had been an issue with your style we wouldn't have been able to help with the info provided in the question so far.